# Find and replace strings in vim on multiple lines

Tags: vim, vi

I can do `:%s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g` for replacing a string across a file, or `:s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/` to replace in current line.

How can I select and replace words from selective lines in vim?

Example: replace text from lines `6-10`, `14-18` but not from `11-13`.

Comment: See also [vim select/edit multiple non sequential lines at once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16439297).

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Comment: [Find and Replace in Vim / Vi](https://linuxize.com/post/vim-find-replace/)

Answer (score 325, accepted):

The `:&&` command repeats the last substitution with the same flags. You can supply the additional range(s) to it (and concatenate as many as you like):

```
:6,10s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g | 14,18&&
```

If you have **many ranges** though, I'd rather use a loop:

```
:for range in split('6,10 14,18')| exe range 's/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g' | endfor
```

Comment: Thanks. Note for future users - `:6,10s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g | :14,18&& | :20,23&& | :28,31&&` will also work, `for` loop makes it more easy to remember and execute.

Comment: Glad you like it! The `:` on the subsequent commands is optional, btw, so you can save some more keystrokes.

Comment: It works without the 'g' at the end in my vim. So maybe when you specify the line range it doesn't need global flag

Comment: @TayyarR The range covers the lines (vertically, so to speak), while the 'g' flag determines whether only one or all matches within the line (so horizontally) are replaced.

Comment: Very nice that I can almost use it like python in the vim cmd. I needed this for lines 56,61,66... in increment of 5 so I used: `:for i in range(56,100,5)|exe i 's/lol/huh/g'| endfor`

Answer (score 772):

Replace All:

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
```

Find each occurrence of 'foo' (in all lines), and replace it with 'bar'.

For specific lines:

```
:6,10s/foo/bar/g
```

Change each 'foo' to 'bar' for all lines from line 6 to line 10 inclusive.

Comment: And what about line 14-18?

Comment: You will have to use the same command again. Vim remembers like rightly said by @Lieven .. Thanks .

Comment: what is the purpose of /g here? Sorry I'm new to linux

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan The final part of this expression, after the last `/`, is where you indicate flags for the operation. This command will normally replace the _first_ match on a line; With the `g` flag it will replace all occurrences.

Comment: You should really reference your sources (i.e, vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace), if you are going to copy and past another person's work.

Comment: The `%` thing does the work! Otherwise, it's just only the first occurrence.

Comment: `%` => run this command on all lines. `g` => match multiple occurences in the same line.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan it has been said what `g` is for. Just to make it more easy to remember it, it stands for `global`, so in the whole file.

Comment: @shaahiin, thank for your prev comment, just want to know, what does `%s` do, if `%` only is sufficient.?

Comment: @kishore `:s` is short for the `:substitute` command. The prefix (`%` in this case) is added to simply specify the **range** over which you want to run the substitute command. `:%s` => run the substitute command on all lines, `:1,8s` => run the substitute command from lines 1 to 8, and so on. `%` is the same as `1, $`. You can read more about ranges from this wiki page - https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Ranges

Answer (score 86):

As a side note, instead of having to type in the line numbers, just highlight the lines where you want to find/replace in one of the visual modes:

- **`VISUAL`** mode (<kbd>V</kbd>)
- **`VISUAL BLOCK`** mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)
- **`VISUAL LINE`** mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, works best in your case)

Once you selected the lines to replace, type your command:

```
:s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
```

You'll note that the range `'<,'>` will be inserted automatically for you:

```
:'<,'>s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
```

Here `'<` simply means *first highlighted line*, and `'>` means *last highlighted line*.

Note that the behaviour might be unexpected when in **`NORMAL`** mode: `'<` and `'>` point to the start and end of the last highlight done in one of the **`VISUAL`** modes. Instead, in **`NORMAL`** mode, the special line number `.` can be used, which simply means *current line*. Hence, you can find/replace only on the current line like this:

```
:.s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
```

Another thing to note is that inserting a second `:` between the range and the find/replace command does no harm, in other words, these commands will still work:

```
:'<,'>:s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
:.:s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
```

Comment: > Example: replace text from lines 6-10, 14-18 but not from 11-13.

— doesn't your reply answer this very question, does it?

Comment: This is a great answer to do it visually instead of noting down the line numbers , thanks :)

Answer (score 65):

### Search and replace

```
:%s/search\|search2\|search3/replace/gci
```

g => global search

c => Ask for confirmation first

i  => Case insensitive

## If you want direct replacement without confirmation, use below command

```
:%s/search/replace/g
```

## If you want confirmation for each replace then run the below command

```
:%s/search/replace/gc
```

## Ask for confirmation first, here search will be case insensitive.

```
:%s/search/replace/gci
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to address the question?

Comment: In my opinion it does, and it gives even more. I was looking specifically for the confirmation part.

Answer (score 35):

You can do it with two find/replace sequences

```
  :6,10s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
  :14,18s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g
```

The second time all you need to adjust is the range so instead of typing it all out, I would recall the last command and edit just the range

Answer (score 31):

In vim if you are confused which all lines will be affected, Use below

```
 :%s/foo/bar/gc
```

Change each 'foo' to 'bar', but ask for confirmation first.
Press 'y' for yes and 'n' for no. Dont forget to save after that

```
:wq
```

Comment: You can actually use the `c` flag in addition to specifying the range, so `:6,10s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/c` works. `c` stands for `confirm`. I use the `c` flag quite often to prevent from accidentally replacing words where I didn't thought about that they exist there as well.

Answer (score 21):

VI search and replace command examples

Let us say you would like to find a word called “foo” and replace with “bar”.

First hit `[Esc]` key

Type : (colon) followed by `%s/foo/bar/` and hit [Enter] key

`:%s/foo/bar/`

Comment: Your `:%s/<search_string>/<replace_string>/g` command will replace all occurrences in the whole file. Not exactly the answer to the question, but useful nonetheless :)

Comment: @tanius Actually it was the most straight forward answer to my problem. You can consider modifying the question to "Find and replace strings in vim on "Selected" lines"

Answer (score 20):

We don't need to bother entering the current line number.

If you would like to change each `foo` to `bar` for current line (`.`) and the two next lines (`+2`), simply do:

```
:.,+2s/foo/bar/g
```

If you want to confirm before changes are made, replace `g` with `gc`:

```
:.,+2s/foo/bar/gc
```

Comment: Another nice thing that I often use is `:.,$s/foo/bar/gc` to search&replace starting from the current line up to the end of the file.

Answer (score 6):

**To answer this question:**

`:40,50s/foo/bar/g`

replace foo with bar in these lines between the 40th line and the 50th line(inclusive), when execute this command you can currently in any line.

`:50,40s/foo/bar/g`

also works, vim will ask you for comfirm and then do the replacement for you as if you have input the first command.

`:,50s/foo/bar/g`

replace foo with bar in these lines between the line you are currently in and the 50th line(inclusive). (if you are in a line AFTER the 50th line vim will ask for confirm again)

**To clearity the difference between vim and the vrapper plugin of Eclipse:**

Note that in varpper

`:,50s/foo/bar/g` command will NOT work.

`:50,40s/foo/bar/g` will work without asking for comfirmation.

(For Vrapper Version 0.74.0 or older).

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the range through visual selection is ok but when there are very
simple operations over just a couple of lines that can be selected by an
operator the best would be to apply these commands as operators.

This sadly can't be done through standards vim commands. You could do a sort
of workaround using the ! (filter) operator and any text object. For
example, to apply the operation to a paragraph, you can do:

```
!ip
```

This has to be read as "Apply the operator ! inside a paragraph". The filter
operator starts command mode and automatically insert the range of lines
followed by a literal "!" that you can delete just after.
If you apply this, to the following paragraph:

```
1
2  Repellendus qui velit vel ullam!
3  ipsam sint modi! velit ipsam sint
4  modi! Debitis dolorum distinctio
5  mollitia vel ullam! Repellendus qui
6  Debitis dolorum distinctio mollitia
7  vel ullam! ipsam
8
9  More text around here
```

The result after pressing "!ap" would be like:

```
:.,.+5
```

As the '.' (point) means the current line, the range between the current
line and the 5 lines after will be used for the operation. Now you can add
the substitute command the same way as previously.

The bad part is that this is not easier that selecting the text for latter
applying the operator. The good part is that this can repeat the insertion
of the range for other similar text ranges (in this case, paragraphs) with
sightly different size. I.e., if you later want to select the range bigger
paragraph the '.' will to it right.

Also, if you like the idea of using semantic text objects to select the
range of operation, you can check my plugin
[EXtend.vim](https://github.com/saulaxel/EXtend.vim) that can do the same
but in an easier manner.

Answer (score -7):

```
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal
```

Suppose if you want to replace the above with some other info.

`COMMAND(:%s/\/sys\/sim\/source\/gm\/kg\/jl\/ls\/owow\/lsal/sys.pkg.mpu.umc.kdk./g)`

In this the above will be get replaced with (`sys.pkg.mpu.umc.kdk.`) .

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the question. From the question it appears the person asking is already aware of how to use `%s` to modify input but wants to know how to do it "semi-globally" (i.e. his specification is lines 6-10 and 14-18 but not on lines 11-13).

Comment: Also what is "COMMAND"? And  you're suffering from [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Comment: To cure that syndrome, you can use another character as delimiter instead of the default `/`, e.g. `!`, `@`, `_` : `:%s_/sys/sim/source/gm/kg/jl/ls/owow/lsal_sys.pkg.mpu.umc.kdk_g`