# search and replace through multiple ranges in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to search/replace through one range of lines and through a second range of lines, via a single command.

[Find and replace strings in vim on multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994922/find-and-replace-strings-in-vim-on-multiple-lines) says I should be able to do it like this:

`:2,10s/\n/ /g | 12,18&&`

but that just gives me:
*9 substitutions on 1 line* for the first range (as expected), and *E16: Invalid range* for the second.

Why doesn't the second range work?

I've also tried the command like:

`:2,10s/\n/ /g | :12,18&&`

with the same result.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994922/find-and-replace-strings-in-vim-on-multiple-lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994922/find-and-replace-strings-in-vim-on-multiple-lines) I believe you will find the answer in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haha... ok, replacing linebreaks with spaces in the first range causes my second range to not exist, as lines 12-18 change to something like 3-9.  Solution is to flip the ranges so the range later in the file comes first in the command:

`:12,18s/\n/ /g | 2,10&&`

Answer (score 2):

Reversing the ranges is helpful here, another approach would be to set *marks* for the subsequent ranges. Vim automatically adapts those for additions / deletions:

```
:12mark a | 18mark b | 2,10s/\n/ /g | 'a,'b&&
```

In general, it's best to avoid such sequences; often, a single `:global` command can do the iteration for you (and this also has automatic line adaptation).