# How to replace a `\norm{ some string }` by `\| some string\|` quickly?

Tags: vim, replace

I am editing a markdown file with vim. This file exist many string `\norm{ some string }`. I want to replace them by `\| some string \|`. Does there exist any quick way? Thanks very much.

The answer in [Find and replace strings in vim on multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994922/find-and-replace-strings-in-vim-on-multiple-lines) can not answer my question. It just talk about general replacing for one line and multi line. Here I want to replace a surrounding and keep the string in the surrounding.

Comment: The `some string` may include some bracket pair `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are so-called capture groups and backreferences. Provided there are no nested forms (curly braces inside do not mean a problem in themselves) and forms spanning multiple lines, a quick solution could be: `%s/\\norm {\(.*\)}/\\|\1\\|/g`.

The `\1` in the substitution part refers to the group captured by `\(.*\)`, i.e. the original content inside the outermost pair of curly braces. See e.g. http://www.vimregex.com/#backreferences for more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This reply can partially answer my question. There exist some  `{}` in my case, eg. `\norm{ A^{-1} }`.

Comment: @HuayiWei he's giving you the resources to find what you need to figure out how to do it yourself, he's not going to give you the exact regex.

Comment: @StunBrick  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @HuayiWei Sorry, that was a typo, "do _not_ mean a problem" was intended. If yout try it, you can see that it works with your example, and the result will be `\| A^{-1} \|`. The case which this regex cannot handle is e.g. `\norm { ... \norm { ... } }` (but you could do multiple rounds :) ). If you have arbitrary levels of nesting, that actually cannot be handled by a simple regex form at all, since you need some form of recursion for that. See for this e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759004/how-to-match-string-within-parentheses-nested-in-java.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a macro to accomplish what you want.

Place your cursor on the first line that have the pattern you want to substitute. Then start recording the macro:

```
qq0ldwr|$xi\|ESCjq
```

Meaning:

```
qq  = start recording a macro (q) in register q
0   = move to the beginning of the line
l   = move one char to the right
dw  = delete the word
r|  = substitute what is under the cursor with a "|"
$   = move to the end of line
x   = delete last char of the line
i   = insert mode
\|  = insert chars "\|"
ESC = exit insert mode
j   = move to next line
q   = stop recording
```

Execute the macro with:

```
@q
```

Execute the macro once again:

```
@@
```

Keep doing it for as many lines as needed, or use:

```
<number>@@
ex. 100@@
```

To execute the macro **number** times.